# Refresh All Access Data Connections in Excel Unprotect and Protect Workbook Error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have some code that pulls in parameters from cells in excel into the data connection that is connected to an access database.  It works perfectly fine but the refreshall code does not work unless the entire worksheet is already unprotected and I don't attempt to protect it back again.  I also have it where the workbook is protected using code right when the excel file opens using code such as this (for each sheet):

```
    Sheets("Name of WorkSheet").Protect Password:="password", Userinterfaceonly:=True
```

However, for refreshing data connections even if userinterfaceonly = true it will not refresh.  In this case I unprotect every worksheet before I run the code and then protect them back at the end.  However, its not refreshing the data connections in the excel file before it protects all the worksheets back even though I have the refreshall code before the protect lines of code (it throws an error saying that it can't update a protected worksheet?  Now if I don't try to protect the worksheets back at the end and keep the unprotected it will update just fine.  However, I need it to protect the worksheets back. 
 Here's my code (I have also tried putting the refreshall command right before the message box too but it still throws the error that some of the sheets are protected and could not refresh):

```
Sub RefreshQuery()

Sheets("Crosswalks").Unprotect "password"
Sheets("New Initiative Plan Form").Unprotect "password"
Sheets("Resubmit Round 1 to 2 Form").Unprotect "password"
Sheets("Total Plan Summary").Unprotect "password"
Sheets("Detail of Rollover Plan").Unprotect "password"
Sheets("Additional Info").Unprotect "password"
Sheets("Access Data").Unprotect "password"



On Error GoTo ErrMsg


valueToFilter = "Plan_Items_Qry_UniqueKey.BuyerName ="

With 
 ActiveWorkbook.Connections("For_Updating_Round1_to_Round2").OLEDBConnection
 queryPreText = .CommandText
 paramPosition = InStr(queryPreText, valueToFilter) + Len(valueToFilter) - 1
 queryPreText = Left(queryPreText, paramPosition)
 queryPostText = .CommandText
 queryPostText = Right(queryPostText, Len(queryPostText) - paramPosition)
 queryPostText = Right(queryPostText, Len(queryPostText) - 
 InStr(queryPostText, ")") + 1)
 .CommandText = queryPreText & " '" & Range("C1").Value & "'" & 
 queryPostText
  End With

 Dim queryPreText2 As String
 Dim queryPostText2 As String
 Dim valueToFilter2 As String
 Dim paramPosition2 As Integer

 valueToFilter2 = "Plan_Items_Qry_UniqueKey.PlanYear ="

 With 
 ActiveWorkbook.Connections("For_Updating_Round1_to_Round2").OLEDBConnection
 queryPreText2 = .CommandText
 paramPosition2 = InStr(queryPreText2, valueToFilter2) + Len(valueToFilter2) 
 - 1
 queryPreText2 = Left(queryPreText2, paramPosition2)
 queryPostText2 = .CommandText
 queryPostText2 = Right(queryPostText2, Len(queryPostText2) - 
 paramPosition2)
 queryPostText2 = Right(queryPostText2, Len(queryPostText2) - 
 InStr(queryPostText2, ")") + 1)
 .CommandText = queryPreText2 & Range("C2").Value & queryPostText2
 End With

 Dim queryPreText3 As String
 Dim queryPostText3 As String
 Dim valueToFilter3 As String
 Dim paramPosition3 As Integer

 valueToFilter3 = "Plan_Items_Qry_UniqueKey.Round ="

 With 
 ActiveWorkbook.Connections("For_Updating_Round1_to_Round2").OLEDBConnection
 queryPreText3 = .CommandText
 paramPosition3 = InStr(queryPreText3, valueToFilter3) + Len(valueToFilter3) 
 - 1
 queryPreText3 = Left(queryPreText3, paramPosition3)
 queryPostText3 = .CommandText
 queryPostText3 = Right(queryPostText3, Len(queryPostText3) - 
 paramPosition3)
 queryPostText3 = Right(queryPostText3, Len(queryPostText3) - 
 InStr(queryPostText3, ")") + 1)
 .CommandText = queryPreText3 & Range("C3").Value & queryPostText3

 End With




 MsgBox ("The Table below has been updated! Please Update any information 
 needed on these initiatives (DO NOT ADD NEW INITIATIVES HERE) and then 
 click Step 2 to resubmit them for Round 2 (Final Round).  If you need to 
 also add additional initiatives for Round 2 Please use the New Initiative 
 Plan Form tab to submit them."), , "Plan Resubmission of Round 1 
 Initiatives to Round 2"

 ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

 Sheets("Crosswalks").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Access Data").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Resubmit Round 1 to 2 Form").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("New Initiative Plan Form").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Total Plan Summary").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Detail of Rollover Plan").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Additional Info").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True



 Exit Sub

 ErrMsg:
 MsgBox ("There was an Error Refreshing the data, please contact Finance"), 
 , "Refresh Error"

 Sheets("Crosswalks").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Access Data").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Resubmit Round 1 to 2 Form").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("New Initiative Plan Form").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Total Plan Summary").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Detail of Rollover Plan").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True
 Sheets("Additional Info").Protect Password:="password", 
 Userinterfaceonly:=True

 Exit Sub

 End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure that the BackGround property of the table are not set to true. Those objects are refreshed asynchronously.

Comment: @VincentG Thanks! That did the trick! One more quick question. Looking at my code quickly, should I be closing these connections afterwards?  And if so, how would I? Or is this okay to do it as I have it? Multiple people will be using this template at same time and all of the connections are setup as read only so they cannot lock the database.  However, just wondering in general about this code not necessarily closing the connection?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to close the connection without removing it. [This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4887ff32-d799-4451-a1fe-91465f4d57da/disconnect-ms-queryexcel-pivot-table-after-refresh?forum=isvvba) seems to indicate you only need to make the connection read only.